# JavaScript Calculating a value every 15 minutes and resetting it at midnight

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am trying to calculate a value, starting at midnight, every 15 minutes and reset the value to 0 at midnight.

The idea is to check the time every minute and at midnight(00:00) set a new interval of 15 minutes for doing the calculations.

I am using this:

```
setInterval(function() { 
    var date = new Date(); 

    if(date.getHours() == 0 && date.getMinutes() == 0){ 
       setInterval(calcFunction, 900000);
    }
}, 60000);

var calcFunction = function() { 
    var myValue = 0;

    if(date1.getHours() == 0 && date1.getMinutes() == 0) {// Check for midnight
        myValue = 0;        // resets value
    } else {
        myValue=myValue + Math.random();  
    }

    console("Value: " + myValue);
};
```

The thing is this is not working properly. The value is calculated every minute and resetting every 4 days.

Comment: Move `var myValue = 0` outside the function.

Comment: Your outer most `setInterval` is set to 60000, so there's your one minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easier way to get a function to call on every quarter hour (00, 15, 30, 45) is to use the `%` (modulo) operator:

```
setInterval(function() { 
    var date = new Date(); 

    if((date.getMinutes() % 15) === 0){ 
       calcFunction();
    }
}, 60000);
```

Also your `calcFunction` is setting `myValue = 0` inside the function, meaning it will be reset to zero every single time it is called, you'd probably want to move it outside of the function.